# Page Rendering Issue with Django and Twitter-Bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Django and was going through the [Django Book](http://djangobook.com/) for the first time.  I tried just throwing some bootstrapped html into a file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
</head>
<body>
    <header><a href="index.html" title="Home"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Test" /></a></header>
    <div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
        <br /><br />
        <form class="search form-inline" action="searchresults.html">
            <div class="input-append">
                <input class="search-input input-xxlarge" id="appendedPrependedInput" size="16" type="text" placeholder="Type in your search"><button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" type="submit">Search</button>
                </div>
            <!--<input type="text" class="search-input input-xlarge" placeholder="Type in your search">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-danger">Search</button> -->
        </form>

        <hr class="soften">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And rendered it with this view:

```
def search(request):
    return render_to_response('search_page.html')
```

When I start a test server using `python manage.py runserver` I get a plain ugly html page, rather than a bootstrapped page.  Why is this?  (I do have the bootstrap assets in the same directory)

Comment: your static files are probably not set up properly. Go to "View Source" and click on the CSS files & see if you get a 404.

Comment: Here's how to set up your static files directory: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: You should answer the question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static files are probably not set up properly. Go to "View Source" and click on the CSS files & see if you get a 404.

Here's how to set up your static files directory: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files

Answer (score 1):

I'd also recommend checking out [django-bootstrap-toolkit](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit).